# for repetindo apenas uma unica vez

Tags: c++, data, c++11

Código:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{

auto time = std::time(nullptr);

std::string lang_utf[6]={"pt_BR.utf8","en_US.utf8","en_GB.utf8","de_DE.utf8","ja_JP.utf8","ru_RU.utf8"};
    std::string lang[6]={"pt_BR: ","en_US: ","en_GB: ","de_DE: ","ja_JP: ","ru_RU: "};

    //std::cout << "Undefined: " << std::put_time(std::gmtime(&time), "%c") << "\n";

    for(int i=0; i<6;i++)
    {
     std::cout.imbue(std::locale(lang_utf[i]));
     for(int j=0; j<6;j++)
     { 
      std::cout << lang[j] << std::put_time(std::gmtime(&time), "%c") << "\n";;        
     }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
pt_BR: seg 16 out 2017 20:07:50 GMT
en_US: seg 16 out 2017 20:07:50 GMT
en_GB: seg 16 out 2017 20:07:50 GMT
de_DE: seg 16 out 2017 20:07:50 GMT
ja_JP: seg 16 out 2017 20:07:50 GMT
ru_RU: seg 16 out 2017 20:07:50 GMT
pt_BR: Mon 16 Oct 2017 08:07:50 PM GMT
en_US: Mon 16 Oct 2017 08:07:50 PM GMT
en_GB: Mon 16 Oct 2017 08:07:50 PM GMT
de_DE: Mon 16 Oct 2017 08:07:50 PM GMT
ja_JP: Mon 16 Oct 2017 08:07:50 PM GMT
ru_RU: Mon 16 Oct 2017 08:07:50 PM GMT
pt_BR: Mon 16 Oct 2017 20:07:50 GMT
en_US: Mon 16 Oct 2017 20:07:50 GMT
en_GB: Mon 16 Oct 2017 20:07:50 GMT
de_DE: Mon 16 Oct 2017 20:07:50 GMT
ja_JP: Mon 16 Oct 2017 20:07:50 GMT
ru_RU: Mon 16 Oct 2017 20:07:50 GMT
pt_BR: Mo 16 Okt 2017 20:07:50 GMT
en_US: Mo 16 Okt 2017 20:07:50 GMT
en_GB: Mo 16 Okt 2017 20:07:50 GMT
de_DE: Mo 16 Okt 2017 20:07:50 GMT
ja_JP: Mo 16 Okt 2017 20:07:50 GMT
ru_RU: Mo 16 Okt 2017 20:07:50 GMT
pt_BR: 2017年10月16日 20時07分50秒
en_US: 2017年10月16日 20時07分50秒
en_GB: 2017年10月16日 20時07分50秒
de_DE: 2017年10月16日 20時07分50秒
ja_JP: 2017年10月16日 20時07分50秒
ru_RU: 2017年10月16日 20時07分50秒
pt_BR: Пн 16 окт 2017 20:07:50
en_US: Пн 16 окт 2017 20:07:50
en_GB: Пн 16 окт 2017 20:07:50
de_DE: Пн 16 окт 2017 20:07:50
ja_JP: Пн 16 окт 2017 20:07:50
ru_RU: Пн 16 окт 2017 20:07:50
bash-4.4$ g++ -o loc locdate.cxx
bash-4.4$ ./loc
pt_BR: seg 16 out 2017 20:08:36 GMT
en_US: seg 16 out 2017 20:08:36 GMT
en_GB: seg 16 out 2017 20:08:36 GMT
de_DE: seg 16 out 2017 20:08:36 GMT
ja_JP: seg 16 out 2017 20:08:36 GMT
ru_RU: seg 16 out 2017 20:08:36 GMT
pt_BR: Mon 16 Oct 2017 08:08:36 PM GMT
en_US: Mon 16 Oct 2017 08:08:36 PM GMT
en_GB: Mon 16 Oct 2017 08:08:36 PM GMT
de_DE: Mon 16 Oct 2017 08:08:36 PM GMT
ja_JP: Mon 16 Oct 2017 08:08:36 PM GMT
ru_RU: Mon 16 Oct 2017 08:08:36 PM GMT
pt_BR: Mon 16 Oct 2017 20:08:36 GMT
en_US: Mon 16 Oct 2017 20:08:36 GMT
en_GB: Mon 16 Oct 2017 20:08:36 GMT
de_DE: Mon 16 Oct 2017 20:08:36 GMT
ja_JP: Mon 16 Oct 2017 20:08:36 GMT
ru_RU: Mon 16 Oct 2017 20:08:36 GMT
pt_BR: Mo 16 Okt 2017 20:08:36 GMT
en_US: Mo 16 Okt 2017 20:08:36 GMT
en_GB: Mo 16 Okt 2017 20:08:36 GMT
de_DE: Mo 16 Okt 2017 20:08:36 GMT
ja_JP: Mo 16 Okt 2017 20:08:36 GMT
ru_RU: Mo 16 Okt 2017 20:08:36 GMT
pt_BR: 2017年10月16日 20時08分36秒
en_US: 2017年10月16日 20時08分36秒
en_GB: 2017年10月16日 20時08分36秒
de_DE: 2017年10月16日 20時08分36秒
ja_JP: 2017年10月16日 20時08分36秒
ru_RU: 2017年10月16日 20時08分36秒
pt_BR: Пн 16 окт 2017 20:08:36
en_US: Пн 16 окт 2017 20:08:36
en_GB: Пн 16 окт 2017 20:08:36
de_DE: Пн 16 окт 2017 20:08:36
ja_JP: Пн 16 окт 2017 20:08:36
ru_RU: Пн 16 окт 2017 20:08:36
```

Como deveria ser a saída:

```
pt_BR: seg 16 out 2017 20:12:12 GMT
en_US: Mon 16 Oct 2017 08:12:12 PM GMT
en_GB: Mon 16 Oct 2017 20:12:12 GMT
de_DE: Mo 16 Okt 2017 20:12:12 GMT
ja_JP: 2017年10月16日 20時12分12秒
ru_RU: Пн 16 окт 2017 20:12:12
```

Tem como fazer isso da forma correta?

Comment: Se tirar o segundo `for` fica como?

Comment: da erro ele nao encontra a variavel i.

Comment: Agora entendi tirei um for e coloquei a variavel i fora dele..

Comment: for(int i=0; i<6;i++)
    {
      std::cout.imbue(std::locale(lang_utf[i]));
      std::cout << lang[i] << std::put_time(std::gmtime(&time), "%c") << "\n";
}

Testa assim.

Comment: deu certo aqui agora...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não precisa de dois laços para resolver o problema, somente um é o suficiente:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    std::time_t now = std::time(nullptr);

    std::string lang[6] = { "pt_BR", "en_US", "en_GB", "de_DE", "ja_JP", "ru_RU" };

    for( int i = 0; i < 6; i++ )
    {
        std::string loc = lang[i] + ".utf8";

        try
        {
            std::cout.imbue(std::locale(loc));
            std::cout << lang[i] << ": " << std::put_time(std::gmtime(&now), "%c") << std::endl;
        }
        catch( std::exception &e )
        {
            std::cout << lang[i] << " nao suportada!" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compilando código no padrão `C++11` usando o compilador `GCC v5`:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o teste
```

Saída:

```
pt_BR nao suportada!
en_US: Tue 17 Oct 2017 03:25:59 PM GMT
en_GB: Tue 17 Oct 2017 15:25:59 GMT
de_DE: Di 17 Okt 2017 15:25:59 GMT
ja_JP: 2017年10月17日 15時25分59秒
ru_RU: Вт 17 окт 2017 15:25:59
```

Código no [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4201a0f3a5b16430)

**Referência:** http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time

Comment: Nossa pq eu nao tinha pensado em uma forma como essa pra fazer? as vezes me acho inteligente na forma de pensar mas to vendo que do que eu sei nada sei... Agora foi legal deu certo aqui... kkkkkkk